# A problem occurred when I import the package-tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

when I import the package

> from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

It tips me that

> Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence" could not be resolved

thought it notice me the problem, I still can run my code.

[image]

I had tried to delete the head "tensorflow", but it doesn't work. Another problem will happen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

pad_sequences is from keras.utils. You can import pad_sequences by

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
```

Thank You.